# how to auto load unload a custom add-in in Microsoft word using C# VSTO?

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

how I can programatically load and unload a VSTO add-in in Word on button click.

I have unloaded it on event click bu using below code.

```
foreach (Office.COMAddIn addin in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.COMAddIns)
                            {
                                if (addin.ProgId == "DocDrafter")
                                {
                                    addin.Connect = false;
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
```

but on document change and document start I have to load the add-in again.

But once addin is unloaded I am unable to load it again.

Comment: Until you posted your comment I hadn't realized you hadn't thought that part through... Logically, if you unload your add-in you can't use the add-in to re-load itself! So tell us more about WHY you unload the add-in. If it's only for a particular document or document type shouldn't you have a document-level customization, not an application-level add-in? Or should it be an add-in, but parts of the UI not visible at times? Or do you need two add-ins: one for working with documents, the other "invisible" handling the events you mention?

Comment: Actually, I have two version of document... for version 1 I want to use addin.. if user opens version 2 document I want that addin should be disable or should not be visible to user or unload it.. but i user again opens version 1 that document should be present. Actually I am new to vsto and word add-ins so I am not able to find the correct solution.

Comment: Do you have an Add-in? Or do you have a document-level customization? Document-level customizations are specific *to the document* (or a template and all documents created from the template). Add-ins are for the entire Word application. It sounds to me like you need to read in the VSTO documentation on MSDN about document-level customizations.

Comment: I have an add-in, I dont think I hav/need  document-level customization?.

Comment: You need a document-level customization if you want to restrict the custom user interface to just one document, or document type (created from a template). From what you tell us, that's the case (document 1 vs. document 2).

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of possibilities - it depends on what, exactly, you want to do. To begin with, you should (have) read the information in the Word object model Help for the `AddIns` collection and the `Addin` object. (We're talking about Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Addin/s for your VSTO project.)

There are basically two approaches. One is to used the `Installed` property of the `Addin` object which loads (`=true`)/unloads(`=false`) the add-in from the Word UI, leaving it in the list of Add-ins (the list in Word's File/Options/Add-ins tab) so that the user (or your code) can load it again as required. It sounds like this is what you need.

The other approach is to remove/add the add-in to/from that list. Use the `Addin.Delete` method to remove the add-in; use `Addins.Add` to add an add-in to the list.

If you disconnect the Add-in from within the VSTO project, as your code does, I don't think there's any way within the scope of VSTO that you're going to get it to connect, again...

Help topic in the documentation: start here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/addins-add-method-word

Comment: Cindy Meister, please can you show me any one approach in C# code. How can I achieve it.